# JQuery ScrollLeft to Origin and Equal Increments

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I'm a graphic designer by training and a first-time programmer, so please be easy on me. I have two questions that I've researched and have been unable to answer. Here is my live site for reference:

http://andychendesign.com/skindeep/

1:  I'm trying to get the site to scroll all the way back to the left on page refresh (cmd-R in Safari), so that when you click a name and then try to refresh, the scroll bar doesn't just stay in the same position.

I've tried many options, including this one:

```
    <script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { $('html, body').animate({ scrollLeft : 0 },800); });
    }
    </script>
```

but nothing seems to be working.

2: I have little arrows at the bottom of the page that are intended to assist with horizontal navigation once the user has chosen a name. They are controlled by these two functions:

```
    <script>
    function goToByScroll2(id){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollLeft: $("#"+id).offset().left - 600 },'slow');
    }
    </script>

    <script>
    function goToByScroll3(id){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollLeft: $("#"+id).offset().left + 600 },'slow');
    </script>
```

Basically, I want the scrolling increment to be the same, but going back and then forward puts me in a different position. I think this is because it's offsetting relative to the id, and I'm not sure what the best way to resolve this is.

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: It always returns to the original position (left:0) when refreshing in my client. Unless you use hash hooks, this is also the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend the scrollTo plugin for this stuff:
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

I am sure you will get the desired results in a breeze when you use this plugin.

Give it a go, and please report back if you can't get the desired results.

For issue 1:

```
$.scrollTo( {left:'0'}, 800 );
```

Would certainly work.

For issue 2:

```
$.scrollTo( {left:'+=100px'}, 800 );
```

Should do the job.

Comment: I did try using this plugin initially but still wasn't able to get it to scroll to the left on page refresh or to scroll equal increments back and forth.

Comment: With scrollTo you can specify elements to scroll to, that makes it very dynamic. And if you do want to have that equal increment you could use `$(...).scrollTo( {top:'110px', left:'290px'}, 800 );` or relative positions: `$(...).scrollTo( {top:'-=100px', left:'+=100'}, 800 );`. Why did that not work for you?

Comment: For the first issue, I think it's because I can't get the event to occur on page refresh. For the second issue, it's because my scrollTo code is adding or subtracting pixels relative to the div it's positioned in.

Comment: Updated my answer with examples using scrollTo

Comment: I've updated my live site with both pieces of code, and neither seems to function. The arrows now do not work at all.

Comment: Please check you syntax first. There are errors in there. Use firefox and firebug to get rid of them, with syntax errors present, it won't work for sure. (First error: you forgot to properly clause the document.ready clause)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The first piece of code works; I'm still trying to work on the second.